# What is the alternative of BizTalk Party for EDI

Tags: biztalk, edifact

Im currently dealing with an issue wherein Control Number in Party agreement is being reset upon undeploying the application and redeploying it. Thus, we are looking on ways on how to generate the EDI without the use of BizTalk Party.

In addition, is it possible to setup a filter to catch the EDI instead of using the Receiver ID.

Answer (score 1):

Do not look for an alternative. Just prevent re-importing party bindings over and over again. Whenever you re-import the bindings for a party, the control numbers will reset. If you redeploy, consider using incremental changes to the party bindings.

Comment: And if you import it by accident, you still have the option to change it in the party settings.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. One more question though, in the agreement settings/party settings, how would i know what control numbers is now in use? example i use a range from 1-100 and the control number in EDI is now 57. if i accidentally import and want to manually configure the settings how would i know the current controller number in use without finding the last EDI i sent?

Comment: Hold on, what Pieter Vandenheede is saying is *don't import/export the Parties at all.*  If you do, just up the start id by 1000.  I've never, ever had anyone complain about gaps, just dups, and even that was just one time.